# how to change the date format which assigned to variable?

Tags: jquery

I have the value in variable now i have to change the date format.

Original Format is 14/05/2015

#txtEventDate value contains 14/05/2015

```
var dateTime = $('#txtEventDate').val()
```

Now I want the output as dateformat like 14 May 2015

Comment: What did you try? What is `dateTime` original value?

Comment: Can you post your original format??

Comment: original time is 14/05/2015

Comment: So what did you try? What did Google find about that? Did you follow a tutorial, did you make any attempts?

Comment: i tried but not worked

Comment: `i tried but not worked` ..post what you tried. This question shows no attempt by you to resolve your own issue which really indicates a lack of research effort as this is not a hard topic to find solutions on the web for

Comment: var currentDate = dateTimeSplit[0] + dateTimeSplit[1] + '<sup>' + "th " + '</sup>' + ' ' + dateTimeSplit[3] + dateTimeSplit[4] + ' ' + dateTimeSplit[6] + dateTimeSplit[7] + dateTimeSplit[8] + dateTimeSplit[9];

Comment: update the question with your code instead of dumping in comments